# Required Ledger Query

Tags: sql

I want to make ledger report with using receipt table and bill table

receipt table

```
[Vch_No][VchDate][Chq_InvDate][Chq_InvNo][AccountName][Debit][Credit][ShortDescription] [id]

1001    2020-02-11  2020-02-12  123 cash    9000    0   NULL        6
1001    2020-02-11  2020-02-12  123 fast Ways   0   9000    NULL    1
1002    2020-02-11  2020-02-12  123 cash    18000   0   NULL        6
1002    2020-02-11  2020-02-12  123 raza    0   18000   NULL        4
1003    2020-02-13  2020-02-05  980 cash    9000    0   NULL        6
1003    2020-02-13  2020-02-14  980 fast Ways   0   8900    NULL    5
1005    2020-02-26  2020-02-14  123 cash    10000   0   NULL        6
1005    2020-02-26  2020-02-14  123 ahsan   0   10000   NULL        2
1008    2020-03-03  2020-03-01  90  cash    89000   0   NULL        6
1008    2020-03-03  2020-03-01  90  ahsan   0   89000   NULL        2
1009    2020-03-03  2020-02-24  123 cash    1890    0   NULL        6
1009    2020-03-03  2020-02-24  123 Ali     0   1890    NULL        3
1010    2020-03-03  2020-02-24  123 cash    1890    0   NULL        6
1010    2020-03-03  2020-02-24  123 Ali     0   1890    NULL        3
1011    2020-03-03  2020-03-11  12  ahsan   0   100 NULL        2
1012    2020-03-03  2020-03-20  12  cash    90008   0   NULL        6
1012    2020-03-03  2020-01-20  12  ahsan   0   90008   NULL        2
1011    2020-03-03  2020-03-11  12  Cash    100 0   NULL        6
1006    2020-02-26  2020-02-20  90  cash    9000    0   NULL        0
1006    2020-02-26  2020-02-19  90  ahsan   0   9000    NULL        0
1004    2020-02-13  2020-02-05  980 cash    9000    0   NULL        6
1004    2020-02-13  2020-02-14  980 fast Ways   0   9000    NULL        1
```

Party Bill Table

```
[Id],[InvNo],[VchDate],[AccountName],[VehicleNo],[Weight],[Station],[Cntr_Size],[Cntr_Destination],[MOP],[Party_Freight],[Party_MTSlip],[Party_Detention],[Party_ExtraWeight],[Party_OtherExp],[Party_Munshiyana] ,Party_Rent],[Credit]
1   6002    ,2020-02-13,Fast Ways,    980    ,      50   ,    lhr   ,  40ft    ,     HQ,        Paid    ,    150000 ,     2200,              4000,      3000,      1500,        300 ,      1000,        0
2   ,6001,  2020-02-13, ahsan ,40ft, HQ ,   ,Paid,  15000,  0   ,0  ,0, 0,  0,  0,  0
```

i try this code

```
select VchDate ,InvNo 'Ref', AccountName,[Party_Freight] + [Party_MTSlip] + [Party_Detention] + [Party_ExtraWeight]+ [Party_OtherExp]  -[Party_Munshiyana] -[Party_Rent] 'Debit' ,Credit  from tblPartyDetailLeger pd where id = 1 
union all 
select VchDate, Chq_InvNo 'Ref', AccountName, Debit ,Credit from tblReceipt tb where id = 1
```

This query result

```
Date        Ref    Description Debit    Credit 
13-02-2020  6002   Fast Ways    159400   0       
11-02-2020  123    Fast Ways     0       9000     
13-02-2020  980    Fast Ways     0       9000
```

but i want like this report result..

```
Date        Ref    Description Debit    Credit Balance
13-02-2020  6002   Bill        159400   0       159400
11-02-2020  123    Cash        0        9000     150400
13-02-2020  980    CAsh         0       9000    141400
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: create stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getLedger
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #INSTLED 
    (
         [Date] Date, 
         [Ref] Decimal, 
         [Description] varchar(100), 
         [Debit] Decimal, 
         [Credit] Decimal
    )

    INSERT INTO #INSTLED ([Date], [Ref], [Description], [Debit], [Credit]) 
        SELECT
            VchDate, InvNo 'Ref', AccountName, 
            [Party_Freight] + [Party_MTSlip] + [Party_Detention] + [Party_ExtraWeight] + [Party_OtherExp] - [Party_Munshiyana] - [Party_Rent] 'Debit', 
            Credit  
        FROM
            tblPartyDetailLeger pd 
        WHERE
            id = 1 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            VchDate, Chq_InvNo 'Ref', AccountName, Debit, Credit 
        FROM
            tblReceipt tb 
        WHERE
            id = 1

    SELECT 
        [Date], [Credit], [Debit],
        SUM ([Credit] - [Debit]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS BALANCE 
    FROM 
        #INSTLED
END
```

Step 2:

```
EXEC dbo.getLedger
```

Comment: my code was absolutely right but was wrong word STORED PROCEDURE instead of PROCEDURE in create syntax. can not give down vote.